# How can I run a migration with Entity Framework Core on an encrypted SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, sqlcipher, db-browser-sqlite

I have an ASP.NET Core console application (targeting version 2.2), using Entity Framework Core. I'm trying to connect to an empty, encrypted SQLite database created with [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) for SQLCipher. After creating the connection, I'm attempting to migrate the database, but I'm getting a `'SQLite Error 26: 'file is not a database'.'`

Here is my code:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=Sqlite\test.db;");

connection.Open();

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
var password = "test";
command.CommandText = "SELECT quote($password);";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$password", password);
var quotedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = " + quotedPassword;
command.Parameters.Clear();
var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

services.AddDbContext<SmartContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(connection));

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var context = serviceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();

Console.WriteLine("Migrating sqlite database");

context.Database.Migrate();
```

I'm able to connect to the database in [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt).

I've looked at [this repository](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore) and I have the **SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher (1.1.11)**, **SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green (1.1.11)**, **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (2.2.6)**, **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core (2.2.6)** packages added in my project.

I've looked at a lot of posts on a lot of forums, but none of them mention migrations with encrypted databases. I might be missing something really obvious, but any help getting past this error would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the Password XD

---

Please check the [Specify the key section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli&fbclid=IwAR1HRSlIcmXORyHaoU--ugMmaQAJ3vFheQXx672jkjfnTzIdmsWstkfURtE#specify-the-key) in the official documentation if you have other problem.

> The method for encrypting and decrypting existing databases varies depending on which solution you're using. For example, you need to use the sqlcipher_export() function on SQLCipher. Check your solution's documentation for details.

You can use the SQLCipher API to finish your work:

1. If you want to build a encrypting database,
   just set your connection string, like this:`Data Source = encryptedName.db; Password=YourPassword`
2. if you want to change password in a encrypting database

   ```
   // you can use this in startup.cs
   using var changePasswordDb = new DBContext(
       new SqliteConnection(
               new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder()
                   {
                        DataSource = "encryptedName.db",
                        Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
                        Password = oldPassword
                   }.ToString()
           ));
   changePasswordDb.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"PRAGMA rekey = {newPassword}");

   // or use SqliteConnection
   var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source =encryptedName.db.db;Password=yourPassword");
   connection.Open();
   var command = connection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "PRAGMA rekey = " + newPassword;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```
3. if you want to encrypt a plaintext SQLite database ,  SQLCipher is not support directly. so you can use sqlcipher_export() to get the goal.
   look this [How to encrypt a plaintext SQLite database to use SQLCipher (and avoid “file is encrypted or is not a database” errors)](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/how-to-encrypt-a-plaintext-sqlite-database-to-use-sqlcipher-and-avoid-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-errors/868)

```
// Example
command.CommandText = "ATTACH DATABASE 'encryptedName.db' AS encrypted KEY 'YourNewPassword';SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');DETACH DATABASE encryptedName;";
```

4. if you have some Performance Issue in Asp.net Core and Entity Framework Core ,
   you need to check to these

- [Performance with SQLite and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23099)
- [Entity Framework Core connection management](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/46714416/entity-framework-core-connection-management)
- [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite: Pool Connections #13837](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13837)

5. if you have other Performance Issue , you can check this [SQLCipher Performance Optimization](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-performance-optimization/14)